# Codeigniter NodeJS Socket IO Realtime Chat

Tags: node.js, codeigniter, socket.io

anyone can help me to solve my problem , i wanna make a multiple chat room

My index.html JS code

```
var room        = [];
$('#controls :checked').each(function() {
    room.push($(this).val());
});
```

My index.html HTMl code

```
  <div id="controls" style="height:400px; display: inline-block; width:20%;  background-color:lightyellow;">
        <input id="room1_check" type="checkbox" value="public"/><label for="room1_check">public</label><br/><br/>
        <input id="room2_check" type="checkbox" value="room_2" checked /><label for="room2_check">Room 2</label><br/><br/>
        <input id="room3_check" type="checkbox" value="room_3" /><label for="room3_check">Room 3</label><br/><br/>
        <input id="room4_check" type="checkbox" value="room_4" /><label for="room4_check">Room 4</label><br/><br/>
        <input id="room5_check" type="checkbox" value="room_5" /><label for="room5_check">Room 5</label><br/><br/>
    </div>
```

here piece of my code .... when i checked the room , i want moving room chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get all checked input when a user selects an item, you might want to add an event handler that listens for the check event.

So I will do something like this

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function() {
    var room        = [];

    $('#controls :checked').each(function() {
     room.push($(this).val());
    });

   //see the result...
   alert(room);
});
```

NB: I added a class `.checkbox` to all the check boxes